# Browser caching issues

Tags: php, facebook, caching, cross-browser

I have been recently struggling to find a way of not caching my website pages once a user is logged in, I see many popular sites such as Facebook and Outlook doing this.

I have tried using these PHP headers and they seem to have no effect what so ever.

```
header( 'Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT' );
header( 'Last-Modified: ' . gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s' ) . ' GMT' );
header( 'Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate' );
header( 'Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false );
header( 'Pragma: no-cache' );
```

I really don’t want the users sensitive information being cached, this really causes a problem on sites such as safari that have a ’Top sites page’ and most often caches images will be stored for the thumbnail of the site.

It also causes a problem when the user signs out of the page, when you hit the back button it will take you back into a cached version of the site, but once you try and interact with anything it will then log you back out.

Any help with this guys? How are Facebook and Outlook achieving this?

Comment: I've never experienced that a browser logs you back in. And you can't tell Safari or Chrome to not make a screenshot of your website. They'll just do it, whether you like it or not.

Comment: That's incorrect, Facebook and Outlook will never cache pages when your are logged in. They only Cache the login pages